# Повторное удаление указателя

Tags: c++, память

При вызове конструктора копий указатели ссылаются на один и тот же указатель. И при вызове деструктора повторное удаление указателя.
Вопрос состит в том, как правильное реализовать конструктора копий, что бы в дальнейшем не происходило повторное удаление указателя.

```
#include <iostream>

class Io
{
    public:
        Io (int v) : val(v){};
        virtual ~Io (){};
        int getValue(){return val;}

    private:
        int val;
};

class Count
{
    public:
        Count (Io _io):io_ptr(new Io(_io)){};
        virtual ~Count (){delete io_ptr;};
        Count(const Count &_io)
        {

            std::cout << "COPPY" << std::endl;
        }
        Io* getIo()const{return io_ptr;}
    private:
        Io *io_ptr;
};

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    Count c(Io(12));
    Count c2(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, а вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Это очень плохо. Надо исправить.

Comment: @Harry, вопрос: как исправить конструктор копирования?

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. В приведенном вами коде указатели не будут ссылаться "на один и тот же указатель". В приведенном вами коде конструктор копирования вообще не инициализирует указатель копии, т.е. этот указатель после копирования будет содержать непредсказуемый мусор. Откуда вы взяли "будут ссылаться на один и тот же указатель" - не ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
Count(const Count &_io):io_ptr(new Io(_io.io_ptr->getValue()))
{
    std::cout << "COPPY" << std::endl;
}
```